# 'LIKE' posts from homefeed with Facebook graph api

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I'm trying out the FB Graph API, and I have made this little test site that just displays your home feed. And I've added a like-button so you can like the items in the feed, just like you can on FB.

Now, I have a problem. Because in the [API docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/publishing/) it says that you should post to:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/OBJECT_ID/likes
```

where the 'OBJECT_ID' is the ID of the object. And this works great wherever there is an object (picture, shared story etc), but there isn't always an object. The most common item without an object is maybe a plain-text status update. So if I try to run this code:

```
function fbLike(id) {
  console.log(id);
  FB.api('/'+ id +'/likes', 'post', function(response) {
    if (!response || response.error) {
      alert('Error occured. ID: ' + id);
    } else {
      alert('Great! It worked. ID: ' + id);
    }
   });
}
```

Where there is no object_id I get the error message:

```
'Error occured. ID: undefined'
```

which is obvious because there is no OBJECT_ID. So, what I've done is in my code made an if/else check to see whether there is an OBJECT_ID or not. If not, I'll use the POST_ID instead (response.data[i].id). This however gives me an error in the console:

```
SyntaxError: At least one digit must occur after a decimal point
```

If you don't know, the ID of a post looks something like this: 1796252809_3826036908205 (whereas an OBJECT_ID looks like this: 545978668769904).

So, what I'm curious about is how I can fix this. How do I make a like to a plain text (normal) status update where there is no object_id? I know it's possible because I can log onto FB's website and like that exact same status there.

Summarized: How can I make a like to a normal post?

Hope someone knows how to fix this! :)

Sincerely,
Aleksander.

**EDIT 1:**
The Syntax Error is shown in the console when I try to click the like button. But the fbLike function is not run, because then I would be returned with the id in the console along with an alert message with either an error or an success message. This is how I've set up my like button:

```
var facebook_footer = '<button onClick="fbLike('+object_id+')"> Like </button>';
and
var facebook_footer = '<button onClick="fbLike('+post_id+')"> Like </button>';
```

(I'm saving them as variables in an for loop, and then printing them out to an div using .innerHTML)

The post_id is the id of the post (xxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxx) and the object_id is the id of an object (where that exists) (xxxxxxxxx).

Comment: *When* exactly is that Syntax Error showing? When assigning the variable? When constructing the query? When posting? In the callback? The answer will lead to an actual understanding of the problem.

Comment: The Syntax Error occurs when I press the like button. But the fbLike function is not run, because then I would be returned the id (console.log(id);) and an alert with either a success message or an error message. I don't get that, so it's obvious that the function isn't run and that the error occurs when I try to run the function. But it works fine when I use the object_id (where it exists), but that only contains a series of numbers. The post_id contains a series of numbers, underscore and more numbers.

Comment: Ah, then it must just be a matter of poor escaping after all :) Try adding extra simple quotes to your `facebook_footer` variables like this: `var facebook_footer = '<button onClick="fbLike(\''+post_id+'\')"> Like </button>';`

Comment: `var facebook_footer = '<button onClick="fbLike(escape('+post_id+'))"> Like </button>';`

Comment: @Coox You were completely right. Thank you so much for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like *some* type conversion is going wrong *somewhere*.

I would guess that the POST_ID semantics that includes an underscore could be causing this. You're probably only interested in posting the second half of such an identifier, which reflects the actual OBJECT_ID of the post.

When you fall back to the POST_ID, try this on your variable (supposing it is a string) before posting:

```
// Filter out non-significant portion of POST_ID
// (ie. keep only what's after the last underscore, if any)
id = id.split('_').slice(-1)[0]
```

Comment: Ok, I'll try that as soon as I get back. 
But what good is the first part of the id for if I  have to remove it? Why do they even have it there? 

Another thing: When I'm linking to the post itself (they can press "read at facebook" or something, I'm using the entire ID of the post (facebook.com/[id here]), and that works fine. So I would guess the id is okay, but I'll try it to be sure ;)

Comment: You're right, it is better to use the entire POST_ID, my answer is not best practice. I initially posted this because somehow, I had the (misguided) understanding that the error was returned from the graph API, when it's actually a JS parsing error from Safari :)